# Can I enable bluetooth on a mobile device with java?

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

sorry for my bad english, can someone tha has worked with java on a mobile device (cell phone) tell me if its possible to enable the bluetooth connection of the device from a java application?

thanks

Comment: you mean you want to enable or disable the bluetooth radio?

Comment: you cannot turn on bluetooth using java.but you can use the turned ON bluetooth in J2ME

Comment: Yes, I wanted to enable the bluetooth radio from my application... I guess I will have to instruct the users how to do it then :(
thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @org.life.java, you can connect to bluetooth in java. If BT is turned off, then it will ask permission to turn it on (just like trying to connect to the internet).

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman
are you sure?
have you tried it?

i tried it long time before at that time i informed user to turn it on manually.
can you reconfirm ?

Comment: @org.life.java, I haven't used J2ME with MIDP of CLDC 2.0 (so basically MIDP 1). I clearly remember that whenever you tried activating bluetooth that's off, there's a popup to confirm whether you want an application to use the bluetooth device. I may be wrong in the new version.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433925/how-to-turn-bluetooth-on-off-with-j2me

Comment: @JigarJoshi.. Yes, It is available in j2me (or java) that If BT is turned off, then it will ask permission to turn it on. For that You have to give permissions to your application from Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely possible with J2ME (Java 2 Micro Edition). I did this 3 years back so I have little knowledge.

1. Go to Oracle's Website and download the J2ME libraries/packages from Oracle.
2. Follow example [here](http://today.java.net/article/2004/07/26/getting-started-java-and-bluetooth) and [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/) for tutorial how to connect to bluetooth device.

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
//for enable blutooth(Turn on)
Intent eintent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(eintent, 1);
//for disable(Turn of)
bluetoothAdapter.disable();
```